# Angular2 change detection - enormous amount of iterations

Tags: angular, typescript, amcharts

I am building Angular2 application and I am using AmCharts. Application is working fine but what I have found is that when AmCharts is loaded there is enormous iterations thru change detection tree and it is starting from the top.

We have implemented DoChange to our main component, in most cases AppComponent:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-body',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'main.component.html',
    precompile: [ComponentWithoutAmChart, ComponentWithAmChart]
})

export class MainComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {

    constructor(private router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    ngDoCheck() {
        console.log("change");
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to detect what is exactly triggering change detection tree in Angular2, so that I can create fix for this AmCharts?

Comment: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: Thanks Anshu, I was able to solve problem, but I am still waiting for them to merge my pull request.

Comment: If anyone needs: https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3-angular2/pull/7